# What could have changed all of the &#039; characters in my content to &#039 strings?

Tags: updates

So, I've recently updated a WordPress site to 4.0 (I try to stay on top of updates as much as I can) and noticed that something funny had happened to the ascii html characters that I had in multiple posts/pages across the site.  Well, one character in specific:  the single quote.  I just noticed this problem this morning, and I updated the site to 4.0 last night.  After updating, I only checked to make sure the site was loading, not specifically that all of the content was identical.  So now I have a bunch of links that look like:

2014&#039s 10 Best Supplements

instead of:

2014's 10 Best Supplements

across my entire site.  I'd used the ascii html character for single quote here because I'd initially had difficulty getting the single quote on this page to render correctly in safari.  Regardless, everything has been fine until today.

I'm fairly certain that this has to have happened when I updated WordPress (or possibly one of a short list of plugins) because I have a development site that I haven't synced in months, that uses a separate database, that has also been perfectly fine up until after this update, and now has the same issue.  Yesterday, I ran through all of these updates (WordPress to 4.0 and the plugins that needed it) first on the dev site to make sure that everything would work correctly on the main site.  When I saw that my dev site seemed to be functioning correctly afterward, I updated the main site with the same changes.

When I noticed what had happened to the main site today, I went back and checked the dev site, and sure enough all of the same changes had been made to it.

From what I can tell at this point, I'm going to have to go through and fix all of these instances manually (which won't be an insignificant task), and honestly I don't want to have to do it twice.  Or more, for that matter.

Is this something that could have happened with the update to WordPress 4.0?  I just can't see where else something like this could have changed, as I'm highly doubting that anyone else that has access to the site would have specifically made these changes to not only the main site, but the dev site as well (typically, I'm the only one that messes with it).

I'm at such a loss with this one. I guess I'm mostly just putting this out there to see if this has happened to anyone else and thus if I have any kind of possibility for submitting a WordPress bug ticket without looking like a complete idiot.

I guess there is the possibility that I could restore the site to another dev folder, disable all of the plugins, and update WordPress again to verify that it was the update that did it.  Something to go on, I guess.  In the meantime, anything that anyone else has for me that could be helpful would be appreciated.

Comment: does the conversion only happen after you load the page in the editor?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here.  The ascii html characters are showing on the front-end page as strings because they're all missing the trailing semicolons.  The semicolons are missing from the content within the editor on the back-end page.  If I add the semicolons to the back-end page and update it, they save just fine.  I haven't verified that the semicolons are also missing from within the database, but I can't easily get access to my database right now due to an issue with my current computer, but I'm doubting that I'll find anything different there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-ran the WordPress update to 4.0 on a backed-up version of the site (files and db) and everything went through without a hitch, so I'm not sure what happened.

I did find a plugin (Search and Replace) that helped to replace all of the resultant strings with the ascii html character that they should be.  So, all in all, not too much time lost, but I'm still curious as to what happened.

Comment: What is the plugin  name ??

Comment: Search & Replace.